# Creating an android studio project to run queries on a google cloud sql server using jdbc driver

Tags: jdbc, android-studio, google-cloud-sql

I have an cloud sql instance up and running and have made a link using a jdbc driver to the instance ip using android studio project. I can successfully run queries from an ip address that I insert manually into the google cloud sql settings and not any other network. This makes my app accessible only from certain ip addresses. Is there a way i can authenticate my google cloud sql to all ip addresses. I do not wish to use the google app engine if possible as I believe it will only complicate my application. My app works well enough is there an easy way to access my sql from any network having supplied my username and password in the code itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the console to authorize 0.0.0.0, which will allow connections from any IP address. However, this is not necessarily a good solution. If you embed your database's username and password in your Android app, it can be found by someone else taking apart the apk. If they do that, they will then have complete access to your database. It is more complicated, but you should put some kind of server in front of your database, and have the user authenticate with that server/application, and only have that server communicate directly with your database.

Comment: I am using SSL auhentication...and since the database does not consist of sensitive data priority is not directed towards security